# После подключения django-resized перестала работать ModelForm

Tags: django

Доброго.
Есть задача принять от пользователя картинку и сразу ее ресайзнуть и сохранить на хостинг. После подключения django-resized перестала работать ModelForm, хотя добавление через админку работает корректно, так же корректно работала форма до подключения django-resized. Не могу понять где моя ошибка, как ее найти.

Модель

```
 class real_obj(models.Model):

 faceimg = ResizedImageField(verbose_name='image', size=[100, 50], crop=['middle', 'center'], upload_to='static/imgages/faceimages', blank=True,
                        null=True)
 agent_id = models.ForeignKey(agent)
 owner_id = models.ForeignKey(contragent)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 ...
```

Форма

```
 class real_obj_form(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = real_obj
      fields = ['title', 'owner_id', 'type', 'deal', 'city', 'district', 'adress', 'metro_station',
              'metro_walk_time', 'area','price_total', 'description', 'faceimg']
```

Вьюшка

```
def new(reguest):
   if reguest.method == 'POST':
       form = real_obj_form(reguest.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
         usrname = reguest.user.username
         my_agent = agent.objects.get(login=usrname)
         new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
         new_obj.agent_id = my_agent
         form.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/crm')


   else:
        form = real_obj_form()

return render(reguest, 'new_ro.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Что пишет в логах?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду модуль logging ?
По факту вьюшка  отрабатывает, объект создается, но вместо адреса  картинки загруженной в бд пустота.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что dev-сервер все ошибки пишет в консоль, а боевой в файл. Там-то ответ и надо искать.

Comment: Не пишет никаких ошибок. Все штатно. Заметил что виджет поменялся с загрузки картинки на загрузку файла. И картинка сама грузится как файл. А в админке как картинка.

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли передать файлы в форму:

```
form = real_obj_form(reguest.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: Не решает. И раньше post за просом картинка отлично передавалась.